# Read Environment Variables in generic host without prefix (.NET)

Tags: environment-variables, .net-5, configurationmanager, .net-6.0

I want to read my custom environment variables in .NET 5 or .NET 6. I have some problems. I can only read environment variables with the `DOTNET_` and `ASPNETCORE_` prefixes:

[image: Debug Section]

For example, I can't read that `MyKey=MyValue`:

```cs
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext,configuration) =>
        {
            string myKey = hostContext.Configuration["MyKey"];
            configuration.AddJsonFile($"Airlines/{myKey}.json");
        })
        .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
        {
            services.AddRabbitMQ();
            services.AddSingleton<NiraAvailableFlightsConsumer>();

            services.AddOptions<AirlineOptions>()
                    .Bind(hostContext.Configuration);
        });
```

[image: Debugging with Breakpoint]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-5.0#default-builder-settings) for the default builder says:

> Loads host configuration from:
>
> - Environment variables prefixed with DOTNET_.

So your variable is not read as part of the host context configuration. You can tell the builder to load all environment variables by adding the `ConfigureHostConfiguration` call to your startup:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureHostConfiguration(config =>
        {
            config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
        })
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, configuration) =>
        {
            string myKey = hostContext.Configuration["MyKey"];
            configuration.AddJsonFile($"Airlines/{myKey}.json");
        })
        .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
        {
            ....
        });
```